# Use an equivalent of rosmake on Windows

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, compilation, windows, lsd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Lots of questions have already been asked on the forum but I didn't manage to find an answer, either because the question was outdated and therefore closed, or simply no answer.

I've followed all the tutorial here: http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros
After lots of attempts, I was able to install ROS on Windows and make a [simple Publisher and Listener](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.The_Code) work but now I don't know how to compile pre-existed packages like this one **RGDB-SLAM** : https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam

Rosmake command line doesn't work on Windows

> 'rosmake' is not recognized as an
> internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

Therefore, I would like to know if I can compile packages in windows ?
I did `winros_make` but didn't compile the source code.

Then if I'm not mistaken rosrun doesn't work on windows, right ? So How I can manage this ?

Thank you very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207467/use-an-equivalent-of-rosmake-on-windows/) by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am aswell new to ROS. I followed the same Path as u did and I came to the conclusion that win_ros is deprecated, it only contains roscore and this stuff but it doesnt contain any useful packages like gmapping, slam etc.

win_ros last release was smth in '12 so its pretty old and there is no hope that anybody develops it in the future.

If I am wrong, please any of the users who know more about win_ros/ROS correct me but the use of win_ros doesnt make any sense, since there are no packages.

edit to second part:
I think that there is no possibility to compile packages under windows because they're developed for linux. you can try cmake which is an alternative to make in linux or you try it with Visual Studio which is the most common programm to compile in windows. I would suggest you to stop working with win_ros, I was at exactly the same point as you and decided to go with linux, even though I was completely new to linux.

I dont think you will become happy with win_ros, if you find a way how to compile it, just tell me..

hope I could help,
greetings
Felix

---

Originally posted by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) with karma: 201 on 2015-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on 2015-04-21**:
Felix, thank for your answer. It was I thought also, you're certainly right.
Maybe, others members could confirm that ?

**Comment by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on 2015-04-22**:
Felix actually I began with Linux and I've already use ROS with Ubuntu but for research purpose and to try to export a package on Windows, I wanted to try...But what I'm know now from the internet and you, it's the fact that win_ros is deprecated and useless.
thank you Felix =).